# New lines in js reqular expression

Tags: javascript

Have the next code:

```
var str = "te\nxt";

console.log(str.match(/.*/gm)); // [ "te", "", "xt", "" ]
```

Is it possible to make the new line not divide the result into parts?

Desired result: *[ "te\nxt", "" ]*

Comment: I propose you first of all give a proper example of what result you actually want, for that given input data.

Comment: I propose a re-write with clearer english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?:.*\n?.*)*
```

See it working with an explanation in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aDEQFI/1/)

Comment: Thanks! Modified version: _(?:.*[\n\r]?.*)*_